# Firebase SMS multifactor authentication, error.resolver is undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication, google-identity

I'm following a seemingly outdated documentation page at https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa#choosing_an_enrollment_pattern
When signing in with email + password, I'm expecting to catch error, and then do

```
if (error.code === "auth/multi-factor-auth-required") {
            const resolver = error.resolver
```

But when I logged out the `error` object, there is no such property as error.resolver:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/multi-factor-auth-required). resolver:  undefined
```

Comment: Can you share more lines of your code, as the piece of information you provided here is not enough to understand the issue enough? Also, you may have a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.multifactorerror) if that helps in resolving the issue!

Comment: Any update on this?  I'm facing the exact same issue and can't find anything on it.

Comment: @KyleAbens No update yet. Firebase documentation seems so bad, and I've decided to give up on this particular feature. Please share any news in the future

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found this little gem in the docs for the most recent version of Firebase for JavaScript (version 9 at the time of this post). Most of the MFA docs seem to be referencing the way it was done for version 8.

```
resolver = getMultiFactorResolver(auth, error);
```

You will need to import `getMultiFactorResolver` from Firebase auth.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.multifactorresolver)